# How to open a custom data file from Mail in my iOS Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have no clue where to get started with this. How do I enable "Open in... My App" in Mail, and then how do I load the custom data file into my application?

I don't think I'm wording it very well in my Google searches, as I have not found exactly what I am looking for or anything to lead me in the right direction.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application/2781290#2781290

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266079/why-is-my-ios-app-not-showing-up-in-other-apps-open-in-dialog/11609935#11609935