# How can I make my app appear in UIActivityViewController for text?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, info.plist, uti

I would like my app to appear in the `UIActivityViewController` for text, in other apps. For example, when sharing from the Notes app as shown below.

[image]

Adding the following to the Info.plist didn't produce any visible results (in Notes, Evernote and Simplenote):

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>icon-text-57.png</string>
            <string>icon-text-72.png</string>
            <string>icon-text-114.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Text</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.text</string>
            <string>public.plain-text</string>
            <string>public.utf8-plain-text</string>
            <string>public.utf16-external-plain-​text</string>
            <string>public.utf16-plain-text</string>
            <string>public.rtf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Currently, you cannot add your app into other `UIActivityViewControllers`, unless you create your own UTI and the app ( Notes, Evernote and Simplenote) add code into their app to show yours.

What you are likely referring to, though, is the `UIDocumentInteractionController`, which is different, and there you CAN add your app, and I believe you are doing that correctly.

The things you are trying are all `UIActivityViewControllers` so no matter how hard you try, your app will not show up there.

Quick note to add: A good way to distinguish between is `UIActivityViewControllers` and a `UIDocumentInteractionController` is to see if "Dropbox" comes up in it. From my experience the Dropbox app has a "catch-all" UTI and can take any file so it usually comes up in nearly all `UIDocumentInteractionController`'s. Of course, you'll need to have the app installed

Comment: Is this still true? Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer, but I see "Save to Dropbox" in a plain `UIActivityViewController`, on the second row of icons. I'd like my app to appear alongside it, and it does with a `UIDocumentInteractionController`, but not alongside Dropbox in a `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: @TimCamber Good point. This info is outdated as of iOS 8, where Share Extensions were added and is the correct way. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're `plist` is wrong, see this answer: [Why is my iOS app not showing up in other apps' "Open in" dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266079/why-is-my-ios-app-not-showing-up-in-other-apps-open-in-dialog) but to me it looks like you haven't yet set the `LSHandlerRank`in your `plist`.

Also: make sure you follow Apple's own Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html